# Constructor cannot be applied to given types, required no argument ; found int?

Tags: java, constructor, bluej

I am making a class that converts Roman numerals into arabic numbers, my code complies fine but when i try to make a client class to test it I am getting the error 
"constructor RomanNumerals in class RomanNumerals cannot be applied to given types; required: no arguments; found: int; reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length".

Here is my code where i call the constructor

```
public class RomanConverter {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      TextIO.putln("Enter a Roman numeral and this will change it to an");
      TextIO.putln("arabic integer.  Enter an integer.")

      while (true) {

         TextIO.putln();
         TextIO.put("? ");


         while (TextIO.peek() == ' ' || TextIO.peek() == '\t')
            TextIO.getAnyChar();
         if ( TextIO.peek() == '\n' )
            break;


         if ( Character.isDigit(TextIO.peek()) ) {
            int arab = TextIO.getlnInt();
            try {
                RomanNumerals N = new RomanNumerals(arab);
                TextIO.putln(N.toInt() + " = " + N.toString());
            }
```

And here is the constructor

```
 public void RomanNumerals(int arabic){
        num = arabic;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to instantiate a `RomanNumerals` object using an **overloaded** constructor that you haven't defined.

This

```
public void RomanNumerals(int arabic){
    num = arabic;
}
```

is a method actually, not a constructor. You need to define a constructor this way:

```
public RomanNumerals(int arabic){
    // Initialization
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a constructor:

```
public void RomanNumerals(int arabic)
```

it's a method called `RomanNumerals` that takes an `int`. The no-argument constructor is the default constructor created for you by Java.

All you need to do is removing `void` in order to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This message means that the expected constructor is RomanNumerals() without any aruments, and that the actual constructor RomanNumerals(int) is not defined. In other words, the formal argument list is empty, but the actual argument list is an int.

> constructor RomanNumerals in class RomanNumerals cannot be applied to
>   given types; required: no arguments; found: int; reason: actual and
>   formal argument lists differ in length

The constructor should look like this.

```
public class MyClass {
  public MyClass(int x, double y) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Note that there are no return argments.

What you have identified as a constructor is really a method because of the return argument.